# C Deleting the newline at the end of a string acting weird

Tags: c, string, newline

So I have the following code:

```
printf("the output is: %s.\n", intCAPass);
```

Which prints the following:

```
the output is: intercapass
.
```

So I tried the two following options to get rid of the newline at the end of the string `intCAPass`:

```
intCAPass[strlen(intCAPass)- 1] = '\0';
strtok(intCAPass,"\n");
```

but both give me the following output:

```
.he output is: intercapass
```

So I'm wondering whats going on here.

More info:

OS: Linux

The variable `intCAPass` receive the string from a function that reads a file containing `interca\n`. So, I use a buffer in which I copy the whole file and at the end I do `buffer[len] = '\0';` and at some point I thought it could cause some problems but I don't think so.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Don't just describe the code in words, show it.

Comment: Show more code please... How `intCAPass` is defined and initialized?

Comment: Reeks of `\r\n`. Is there any Windows in your area?

Comment: File comes from Windows?

Comment: Defenestrate it!

Comment: It looks like the `\n` is not in the index you think it is.

Comment: If the source file is supposed to be a *text* file on Linux, then Windows-style line terminators in it should be considered a malformation.  It's one that you might very well want or need your program to handle gracefully, but you do also have the alternative of running the file through `dos2unix` to correct the line termination style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.he output is: intercapass
```

You have a Windows-style CRLF (`\r\n`) line ending in the input string.
When the final newline `\n` is removed, the carriage return `\r` is left in the string. When printed, it moves output back to the start of the line. Thus the final dot overwrites the first letter of the output line.

These should show similar behaviour:

```
printf("string one: %s.\n", "blah\r\n");
printf("string two: %s.\n", "blah\r");
```

Check the character before the `\n` at the end of the string against a `\r`, and remove that one too.

Comment: Yep, fixed. Thank you. I actually thought about it but I thought the files were created under linux. That's also why I mentioned the OS.